# Error writing a file in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, csv, fwrite, swift-playground

Not sure why I am getting the error here. I created the folder 'Shared Playground Data' in documents as instructed. Does anyone have any insight?

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

var fileName = "Csv.csv"
var csvText = "Date,Task,Time Started,Time Ended\n"
fileName.append(csvText)

let fileUrl = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
do {
try fileName.write(to: fileUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {print("error")}
```

Comment: Why don't you change your `catch` to `print(error)` and then you can see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. Why do you append the column headings to the filename? And why do you write the contents of `fileName` to `fileUrl`?

You probably want the following:

```
let fileName = "Csv.csv"
let csvText = "Date,Task,Time Started,Time Ended\n"

let fileUrl = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
do {
    try csvText.write(to: fileUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: got this: `Use of unresolved identifier 'playgroundSharedDataDirectory'`

Comment: @János try importing `PlaygroundSupport`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which Xcode introduced this error, but `playgroundSharedDataDirectory` directory can't be found by Playgrounds on Xcode 13 beta 2, so instead, do this:

#### Swift 5 version

```swift
let docDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let fileName = "Csv.csv"
let outputFileUrl = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

let csvText = "Date,Task,Time Started,Time Ended\n"

do {
  try csvText.write(to: outputFileUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
  print (error)
}
```